# drupal module for making free classified site?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

how to make free classified site (like www.olx.in) using drupal7. where people post there ads.and visitor according to their interest search products and reply to ad publisher.does any drupal module available to accomplish this task.

Comment: There is already a forum for this on Drupal Groups http://groups.drupal.org/classifieds. You could try creating this with CCK and/or existing modules (http://drupal.org/project/modules), or you could also try an installation profile. The closest profile I could find was eRecruiter (which has a different focus, but might be a good starting point) - http://drupal.org/project/installation%20profiles?filters=bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc&text=classifieds. I won't attempt an answer on how to create this with individual modules as that would be a very long post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal distribution system https://drupal.org/project/classified_advertising 
**Features** 
Bootstrap 3 theme, location and gmap.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/ed_classified

It may be sufficient for your needs + it supports drupal 7